# In Hugo, how can I set a site constant variables to be used in the content?

Tags: web, hugo

I am working on a site which is developed with Hugo.

The problem that I am trying to solve is that I have some string that shows up in many pages on the site, so I want to set it to a global variable. I have started to tackle this with [site variables](https://gohugo.io/variables/site/), but I can not get the variable to be used in the content. Is this the way or there is another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a [solution](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/using-a-site-global-string/15554) from the Hugo discussion site, you can use site params by adding a new param into the config.toml [params] for example globalString . Then you could reference the global variable like {{< param globalString >}}.